# Show all products on one page with WooCommerce

Tags: wp-query, plugins

I have WooCommerce running on [this store](http://sergedenimes.com/shop/).

Although the default is to show 12 products on a page the client has asked for a "show all" button that will prevent the user having to use pagination to get to the other products.

Is there a function I can run on the current page that will rerun the loop but change the query to give more 'posts per page'? I've had a poke around the WooCommerce template files but it's not obvious how this is done.

I was thinking on passing a php `GET` variable to the current page and just testing for it to determine whether to run the modified query, like so (outside the loop):

```
<a href="<?php 
echo get_permalink( $post->ID ) . "?showall=1"; 
?>">Show all</a>
```

And then have something like this before template files loop

```
<?php if($_GET['showall'] = 1){ //something here to modify the query (wp_query perhaps?? or a woocommerce filter) } ?>
//the loop as normal
```

Am I on the right track? Is this something that is easy to achieve in this way. Any guidance on how to implement would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
OK I've had a bit more of a dig around the WooCommerce templates. It looks like `archive-product.php` is the file I'd like to override.

Now, I already specify the products per page with a filter in my theme's functions.php as below:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 12;' ), 20 );
```

And Ive added this line in the `archive-product.php` file which I've copied to `my theme folder/woocommerce` to override the default:

```
        <?php if($_GET['showall']==1){ 
            add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 8;' ), 30 ); 
        } ?>
```

When I then visit `shop_page/?showall=1` the filter fails to execute. The filter in functions.php seems to dominate despite having a lower priority.

Comment: did you check woocommerce documentation? http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/change-number-of-products-displayed-per-page/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the conditional check to your `functions.php` file:

```
if( isset( $_GET['showall'] ) ){ 
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return -1;' ) ); 
} else {
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 12;' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but if you don't have to account for php 5.2 it's safer and more efficient to use a closure:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function ( $cols ) {
    return - 1;
} );
```

(See [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) on `create_function`.)

Answer (score 1):

Just read your topic,

I've created a plugin around this to create a dropdown box for the visitor to select the number of products he/she wants to see.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-per-page/

Hope you can use this in your situation.