# Woocommerce custom loop to show all the products

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination, plugins, sort

I'm currently working on an ecommerce website and I met an problem.
My client want a page e-boutique with all the product categories displayed, followed by three promoted products and a button "show all".

This "Show all" button is supposed to show all the product that the store contains with the default woocommerce sorting and paging.

First of all, I dunno I'm doing it the right way. What I have so far is the page showing the product categories and when on this page I click the "show all" button, I reload the page with a `GET` argument `/?all=1` and have the product displayed.

```
<a class="product-category-view-all" href="?all=1"><?php _e('View all'); ?></a>
```

[I copied the idea from this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88370/show-all-products-on-one-page-with-woocommerce), and here is my code:

```
<div id="content" class="hfeed">
<h1><?php _e('The E-boutique'); ?></h1>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['all']))
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => $orderby,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop'); // woocommerce sorting ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <ul class="products-list">
        <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_get_template_part('content', 'product'); ?>

            <?php
        endwhile; // end of the loop. 
        wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop'); // woocommerce pagination   ?>

    <?php
}
else
{
    // Code to display the product categories with thumbnails.
}
?>
```

The products are well displayed and the select for the sorting is visible.
When I want to change the sorting, the page is reloaded but the order isn't changed and the paging is set to 3 products per page but it is not respected. (the paging buttons aren't displayed).

I would like to add that it's my first website using WordPress and WooCommerce.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find an answer for this? If yes, please share. That will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a better post to copy from :) https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't entirely resolved my problem. My client changed his mind and didn't want the sorting anymore.

But concerning the paging, I managed to have it working by adding a new arg in my query, here is the code that made it worked for me :

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if (isset($_GET['all']))
    {
        ?>

        <?php do_action('woocommerce_archive_description'); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php
            // I don't want the sorting anymore
            //do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');
            ?>

            <ul class = "products-list">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_get_template_part('content', 'product'); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop.   ?>
            </ul>

            <?php
            /*  woocommerce pagination  */
            do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');
            ?>

        <?php elseif (!woocommerce_product_subcategories(array('before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start(false), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end(false)))) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_get_template('loop/no-products-found.php'); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        // Code to display the product categories with thumbnails.
    }
?>
```

The `$paged` variable helps me to get the current page passed in the URL via GET.

Once again, I dunno if it is the best way to do it. But it did the job for me.

I hope it can help someone.

Comment: `woocommerce_get_template_part` is deprecated since version 3.0 ... use `wc_get_template_part` instead ... You can as well use a if statement to make your code support both older and newer version of woocommerce

Answer (score 2):

In your $args array, you should be able to add `'posts_per_page' => -1` to show all products. The result would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```